# install XFCE login screen

Tags: 16.04, xfce

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 server version without any GUI, than I installed xcfe4, right now to start xfce4 desktop environment I have to type in terminal

```
sudo startxfce4
```

How can I see a GUI for login when computer starts instead going to command line? I have been searching a lot and I think I need to install a display manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a dm like lightdm or xdm. It should be also part of the xfce4-desktop-meta package.

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you would add how to do this. Please review [this](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)